# Creating table using tabularx and datatool from csv file

Tags: hyperref, tabularx, datatool

I am trying to create a vocabulary list from a csv file containing the vocabulary using tabularx and datatool.

This is what I have tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool,tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
english,german
voasc1,translation1
vofc2,trans2
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb{vocabDB}{test.csv}%Load vocab file

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{X|X}
  \textbf{English} & \textbf{German} \\
  \hline
  \DTLforeach*{vocabDB}{\English=english,\German=german}{
    \English & \German \\
  }
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

But then I get a blank line in the first column. At least there is no TeX error while compiling.

[image]

I tried to use this tabularx syntax without datatool and then it is successful, i.e. each row has just one line and both columns are in the same height.

**EDIT**

It seems to actually be hyperref causing this strange behaviour. (I have added the line to code above). Why does it do that?

**Edit 2**
Solved the issue by placing the table into a NoHyper environment.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I don't receive the output you show. Your MWE has an output that resembles [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DVfr1.png).

Comment: It seems to be hyperref causing this issue. I have added the respective line to the code in my question.
Any ideas why hyperref causes this behaviour?

Comment: Ok so now that I have found the problem I just placed the table into a NoHyper environment so that I do not get this behaviour. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) keeps track of the rows that it parses when using `\DTLforeach[*][<condition>]{<db name>}{<assign list>}{<text>}` (from the [user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/datatool-user.pdf)):

> The macro `\DTLforeach` may be nested up to three times. Each level
>   uses the corresponding counters: `DTLrowi`, `DTLrowii` and `DTLrowiii` which
>   keep track of the current row.
>
> Note that these counters are only incremented when `<condition>` is
>   satisfied, therefore they will not have the correct value in `<condition>`.
>   These counters are incremented using `\refstepcounter` before the
>   start of `<text>`, so they may be referenced using `\label`, however
>   remember that `\label` references the last counter to be incremented
>   using `\refstepcounter` in the current scope. The \label should
>   therefore be the first command in `<text>` to ensure that it references the
>   current row counter.

The important bit here is that the row counter can be referenced using a `\label`. As such, it's incremented using `\refstepcounter` - something that [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) redefines in order to manage its hyperlinking anchors and such.

In order to avoid this, remove `hyperref` functionality for the table (via a `NoHyper` environment), or don't use a referenceable stepping mechanism in the counters. That is, `\let\refstepcounter\stepcounter`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool,tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
english,german
english1,german1
english2,german2
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb{vocabDB}{test.csv}%Load vocab file

\noindent
{\let\refstepcounter\stepcounter% Or \begin{NoHyper}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{X|X}
  \textbf{English} & \textbf{German} \\
  \hline
  \DTLforeach*{vocabDB}{\English=english,\German=german}{
    \English & \German \\
  }
\end{tabularx}%
}% \end{NoHyper}

\end{document}
```

Note that this behaviour is also specific to the `X`-column type of [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) and other fixed-width column types (like `p` or `m`). For example, using an `l`-column doesn't show this problem.

Comment: This seems like a bug, but I'm not sure whether it should be fixed in [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) or [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). I doubt whether [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) is at fault here, and @DavidCarlisle would agree. ;)