# Tables with fixed column widths and language switching

Tags: tables, line-breaking, longtable, babel, columns

I'm trying to typeset a German-Slovak vocabulary list and some grammar. Since table entries might get long, I'm using tables with p-columns. For correct hyphenation, I want to switch to Slovak in the respective column using babel. In order to do this, I defined

```
\newcommand{\slk}[1]{\selectlanguage{slovak}#1\selectlanguage{ngerman}}
```

which switches to Slovak and back to German afterwards. However, if the table is coded with a tabular-environment, there are extra linebreaks in the right column. If I do the same with longtable, no extra linebreaks occur. Is there a way to fix the tabular issue?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[slovak,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{droid}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\newcommand{\slk}[1]{\selectlanguage{slovak}#1\selectlanguage{ngerman}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
Nom.&\slk{môj, tvoj, náš, váš}\\
Gen.&\slk{-ho}
\end{tabular}
\begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
Nom.&\slk{môj, tvoj, náš, váš}\\
Gen.&\slk{-ho}
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The symptoms are quite similar to [Creating table using tabularx and datatool from csv file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223153/creating-table-using-tabularx-and-datatool-from-csv-file) but NoHyper environments do not fix my issue. (Yes, hyperref will be in my final document, too.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'd define `\newcommand{\slk}[1]{\foreignlanguage{slovak}{#1}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicit usage of `\selectlanguage` in a document should be very rare.

In your case the correct command to use is `\foreignlanguage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[slovak,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{droid}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{array,longtable}

\newcommand{\slk}[1]{\foreignlanguage{slovak}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
Nom.&\slk{môj, tvoj, náš, váš}\\
Gen.&\slk{-ho}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\begin{longtable}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
Nom.&\slk{môj, tvoj, náš, váš}\\
Gen.&\slk{-ho}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Note that `longtable` is centered by default. Also I'd not use `utf8x`, but `utf8`.

[image]

Comment: Even works if I add

    \usepackage[russianslovak,ngerman]{babel}

    \newcommand{\rus}[1]{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}

Helps a lot!

Comment: @TeXminator Don't forget to look at [Slovak (and Czech) babel gives problems with `\cmidrule` and `\cline`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111999/) if you plan to use `\cline` or `\cmidrule`.