# Is there a way to make \DTLloaddb load not from external files?

Tags: datatool, csv

The journal has a rule that forbids loading external files and the entire tex file must be self-contained in a single .tex file. Therefore all `\DTLloaddb{aaa.csv}` must be replaced. Is there a way to put the .csv file into the main tex file and make `\DTLloaddb` load certain lines of the main .tex file?

Comment: You're looking for the [filecontents](https://latexref.xyz/filecontents.html) environment. This site has many example, e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223184/208544)

Comment: Alternatively, if you use Datatool to populate a `tabular` environment or an Appendix or something, you can also compile just the table or the Appendix separately to a pdf and include that as an image, e.g., `\begin{table}\includegraphics{mytable.pdf}\caption{...}\label{...}\end{table}`.

Comment: sorry include an external pdf is not the solution that fits this scenario, is there a way to define a database from an "internal" csv file?

Comment: Would you be more specific please? How to define a csv database without resorting to external csv file??